# How to combine a preshared key and a shared secret

Tags: authentication

What is the best way to combine a shared secret generated using elliptic curve diffie-hellman, and a pre-shared key file. I want a way to make sure that both correct keys are being used not just the shared secret or the pre-shared key. Is a simple hash enough? Which hash should I use? Or should I use pbkdf2?

The key is being used to encrypt a message using AES 128 GCM. And it only gets used for one message. A new shared secret is generated for each message.

Comment: Depends on the overall solution. Are you encrypting? Signing? Hashing? Something else? Service call? Data at rest? Need specifics.

Comment: Encrypting a message with AES 128 GCM.